# meaning of a backtick (`) in front of one partition inside cfdisk

Tags: linux, partition-table, cfdisk

I have a disk with a potentially bad partition (`du -sh *` in a particular directory gives me `Structure needs cleaning`). I fired up `cfdisk /dev/sda` to look at the partitions and what I see is:

```
Disk: /dev/sda
Size: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Label: dos, identifier: 0x00000000

    Device Boot Start                        End Sectors                   Size                 Id Type
>>  Free space 2048                       8191 6144 3M
    /dev/sda1 * 8192                      90111 81920                    40M                  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
    /dev/sda2 90112                     729087 638976                   312M                 83 Linux
    /dev/sda3 729088                    1368063 638976                   312M                 83 Linux
    /dev/sda4 1368064                  488397167 487029104                 232.2G                  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
    |-Free space 1370112                    1376256 6145 3M
    |-/dev/sda5 1376256                    1417215 40960                    20M                 83 Linux
    |-Free space 1419264                    1425408 6145 3M
    `-/dev/sda6 1425408                  488397167 486971760                 232.2G                 83 Linux
```

What does the ` in front of `/dev/sda6` stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is part of the character-based tree representation trying to illustrate the relationship between `/dev/sda4` and the lines below it. It is similar to the representations of the directory tree you can get using the `tree` command, although using just the basic ASCII character set.

You might see similar things in any situation where a tree-like structure needs to be described using just plain ASCII and a fixed-width font.

```
This is the main unit
|- this is a sub-unit inside the main unit
|- this is another sub-unit inside the main unit
`- this is the last sub-unit inside the main unit
```

Many variations of this text-based tree representation exist. You might see a backslash used instead of the backtick:

```
This is the main unit
|--- this is a sub-unit
|    \--- this is a sub-sub-unit for the first sub-unit  
|-+- this is a sub-unit that might have sub-sub-units inside it (hidden for now)
\--- this is the last sub-unit inside the main unit
```

It is supposed to look like a line going down from the main unit, with branches for the sub-units, and a 90-degree angle at the last sub-unit, indicating that the group of sub-units within this main unit ends here. Other than that, the specific characters don't stand for anything in particular: they are simply chosen to act as suitably-shaped pieces of the tree graph.